# Regular Expressions in JavaScript for URL Capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not too good with Regular Expressions in Javascript. Does anyone know an efficient way to capture the last portion of a URL???

I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/developers/568d3c3c82eea6e6fb47c236
```

And all I need to do is capture the developer ID (which is 568d3c3c82eea6e6fb47c236). This route will always be the same (with just the ID's changing).

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` by `/` and get the last element of srray:

```
var last = 'http://localhost:3000/developers/568d3c3c82eea6e6fb47c236'.split('/').pop();
//=> 568d3c3c82eea6e6fb47c236
```

Comment: Doing a split is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression; just use `lastIndexOf` method:

```
var developerID = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are built in methods for this:

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()
```

This will get everything after the domain name (`window.location.pathname`), then split it by forward slashes (`split("/")`), then return the last item of the array returned by `split()`, (`pop()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet

```
var loc = location.href; 
var lastPart = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```